# tf.argmax() vs tf.arg_max() in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems `tf.argmax()` and `tf.arg_max()` are doing the same thing for outputting the indies of the biggest element in matrix.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/arg_max

Why does TensorFlow have two APIs for this?

Comment: Probably got renamed to match numpy , but old version had to be kept for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 7):

The following is the source code of `argmax` (from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py).

```
# pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
# TODO(aselle): deprecate arg_max
def argmax(input, axis=None, name=None, dimension=None):
  if dimension is not None:
    if axis is not None:
      raise ValueError("Cannot specify both 'axis' and 'dimension'")
    axis = dimension
  elif axis is None:
    axis = 0
  return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name)
```

As you can see, `argmax` is using `arg_max` inside. Also from the code, I recommend using `argmax` because `arg_max` could be deprecated soon.

Comment: nowdays argmax also gives a warning: calling argmax (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with dimension is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

With TensorFlow version **1.14.0** it's suggested to use `tf.math.argmax` function. And also `dimension` parameter is deprecated instead of it you can use `axis`.

Sample

```
tf.math.argmax(input, axis=1)
```